# How browser access to this script <script hrf="host/script.js">?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, browser

If a javascript file 'script.js' is available in the network. And is wanted bring it to the current browser's windows.

```
<html> 
.
.
.
<script href="host:port/script.js">
.
.
```

What specific internal feature browser uses to communicate and bring the file ?
Is it ajax ?

Comment: no, it's just a network request. ajax is a network request triggered by javascript. browsers don't natively use javascript to load other javascript.

Comment: That's the point. I need to know, What feature browser uses to load other js files ?

Answer (score 0):

The browser will scan the HTML page for links, this can be the script tag with an href, or an img tag, or a link tag with a css. All these links will be fetched via GET requests (or maybe just and HEAD request with some headers to simply ask the server if the file has changed, whern the browser has a previous version of this target in his internal cache).

By definition all GET links can be fetched automatically by the browser without asking for the user permission. That's not the case for POST links (link submit buttons).

One of the use of ajax (there are many) is to perform POST requests without user interactions, or without form submissions.

Ajax is XmlHttpRequest and is a specific way of doing HTTP requests, using the javascript engine. You can always deactivate complety javascript (there are plugins for that) and you will see that a lot of request are still made by the browser, but no ajax request. Here the `script.js` would be fetched, but not interpreted, if javascript is not activated.

So, XmlHttpRequests are requests made via javascript, but you do not always need XhmlHttpRequests to fetch something. For example you can use javascript to add img tags in the document DOM, the browser will detect these new GET and fetch the images.

Comment: Thanks you Regilerio! This clarify my picture.

Comment: Another relational question, if you are so kind.
I understand that those 'GET' of browser, use internal system operative networks features. 
1 - What about security ?
 In the example, this 'public' file 'script.js' if s.o not block (with firewall, middleware or any software in local machine) and js enable, then gonna be executed. What happend if this script.js, create in DOM another link tag, so BROWSER will GET it. 
There's a way to configure headers remotly of these GETs ?

Comment: Mark question as answered when it's answered. About security that's a big question, but the main point is 'same origin policy', things that the linked sources can do are limited by the origin (defined mainly by domain and port).  But a js script can do a loOOoot of things, that's why XSS is dangerous and that's why people should use ad blockers.